# Symfony 2 Bundle - install image resources

Tags: php, symfony, twitter-bootstrap, assetic

I have created a bundle for Twitter Bootstrap by copying the relevant files to the following locations:

- `src/Acme/BootstrapBundle/Resource/public/js`
- `src/Acme/BootstrapBundle/Resource/public/css`
- `src/Acme/BootstrapBundle/Resource/public/img`

Next, I execute `php app/console assets:install web` which copies the bundle resources to the web folder and in my twig template I can use assetic to pull in the css and javascript, which works fine.

The problem I have is that the vanilla bootstrap css is pointing to /img in the web root for the image resources, which are in fact in `/web/bundles/bellabootstrap/img`

I can manually copy these files to the desired location, or even create a symlink, but I want to know what the correct Symfony / Assetic way of doing this is.

Note that I am interested in how to do this not just for Bootstrap - jqueryui/jquery-datatables etc. and other 3rd party libs have exactly the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle to ease your life

Comment: Thanks I have seen this, but I would like to know how to do this not just for Bootstrap - have edited the question to note this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the proper solution for this a while back:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter

Assetic (a great piece of software) can run your CSS through various filters, the one which solves this problem is ccsrewrite, as explained in the Symfony docs it will fix paths contained in your CSS files.

Answer (score 2):

For JQuery UI (smoothness theme) I have:

```
src/Acme/YourBundle/Resources/public/css/smoothness
src/Acme/YourBundle/Resources/public/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
src/Acme/YourBundle/Resources/public/css/smoothness/images
src/Acme/YourBundle/Resources/public/css/smoothness/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
```

... and other image files (just as they came out from the jquery.com site).

In twig I have:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/acmeyour/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css') }}"></link>
```

No need to care for png files location since a good writen css takes care of it for you. The {{ asset() }} method, in the other hand, points to the right directory so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks I can see how that works, and it's a reasonable solution. However I'm using assetic in a way that maps the css & js files to /css and /js instead of using the full bundle path. Maybe there is not a way to do what I am asking, in which case I will resign myself to using your method.